# Drupal always creates its own URL aliases, even when I tell it not to

Tags: path-aliases

I don't know if this is a bug in Drupal, or if there's a configuration somewhere that is causing the problem, but when I create a new page or edit an existing page, Drupal (always? often? sometimes?) generates its own URL alias, even though I've very clearly specified that it should NOT do this, and I've provided one.  The one I provide does get created, but the Drupal-generated URL alias, which is always ugly, gets used instead.  I have to manually delete the Drupal-generated alias in order for the site to work.

For instance, I just added 2 pages, "Privacy Policy" and "Terms of Use".  Even though I specified `/terms` and `/privacy` as the URLs (and yes: of course I gave them to Drupal without the initial slashes), I got stuck with `/content/privacy-policy` and `/content/terms-of-use` as the URLs for these pages.

Comment: I don't want to have manage them for *everything*, I just want it to honor my choice when I uncheck "Generate automatic URL alias".  It's actually useful for news stories and such.

Comment: That's weird. Try this: For PathAuto's configuration, don't provide a pattern for the node types you do not want alias' created for. In addition, make sure the "default pattern" for nodes is also not set. That should prevent it from generating an alias automatically and force it to pick up yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an existing bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/936222. Try applying the patch there.

Comment: That's a bug in Drupal?  Or Pathauto?

Comment: (HOLY &!@% that's four years old and they haven't merged the fix into the main code base!?)

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same issue. I found the reason why it was behaving like that, so I thought I would post the answer here for others with the same problem.

You need to go to **Path Settings** --> Section "**While Updating**" (I don't know the exact wording in English as I have the PT version).

Here, you have to select the first option: **Do nothing. Keep the old alternative path**.

This should solve your question. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'll give it a try when I get a chance.  Doesn't it strike you as an egregious flaw in Drupal that we're forced to do this, and that it ignores the setting for "Generate automatic URL alias"?